# UnimplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d". DNN library is not found. [Op:Conv2D] Call arguments received:

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was trying to run a transformer code shown here: https://github.com/iamrakesh28/Video-Prediction

When I train the model:

```
shifted_movies = tf.convert_to_tensor(generate_movies(n_samples=1200), dtype=tf.float32)
print(shifted_movies.shape)

X = shifted_movies[:, :10, :, :, :]
Y = shifted_movies[:, 10:, :, :, :]

# defines the model
model = VideoPrediction(
    num_layers=3, d_model=64, num_heads=16, dff=128,
    filter_size=(3, 3), image_shape=(40, 40), pe_input=10,
    pe_target=20, out_channel=1, loss_function='bin_cross'
)
model.train(X[:1000, :5], X[:1000, 5:], None, None, 1, 8)
```

I got this:

```
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7704/3895242283.py in <module>
----> 1 model.train(X[:1000, :5], X[:1000, 5:], None, None, 1, 8)
~\OneDrive\LBL\all_code3\Video-Prediction-master\Video-Prediction-master\transformer_video\video_prediction.py in train(self, inp, tar, inp_val, tar_val, epochs, batch_size, epoch_print)
     50                 dec_inp = tar[index:index + batch_size, :, :, :]
     51 
---> 52                 batch_loss = self.train_step(enc_inp, dec_inp)
     53                 total_loss += batch_loss
     54 

……
……
UnimplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d" (type Conv2D).

DNN library is not found. [Op:Conv2D]

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(8, 5, 40, 40, 1), dtype=float32)
```

By the way, the configuration in my environment is:

```
tensorflow                2.8.0                    
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.24.0                
tensorflow-probability    0.16.0                   
cudnn                     6.0                      
cudatoolkit               11.3.1
```

The shape of the inputs

```
(1200, 20, 40, 40, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.8.0 is compatible with `cudnn 8.1` and `cudatoolkit 11.2`, according to the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Please try again after installing the compatible versions using the code below. Thank you!

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
```